# How to make APScheduler ProcessPoolExecutor close process upon completion and only spawn processes it needs?

Tags: python, apscheduler

ProcessPoolExecutor spawns a bunch of processes that handle apscheduler jobs. I expect the processes spawned by ProcessPoolExecutor to actually be shutdown upon successful completion of the job and a new process to be spawned for the next execution of said job. I also expect to not spawn processes if there is no need to. This however doesn't happen. If I set max workers to 10, 10 processes will be spawned. Even if the only job has max_instances of 3. After one of the processes completes the job, the process isn't reclaimed and is merely repurposed for the next run of said job.

I'll give an example:

Create an apscheduler utilizing BlockingScheduler using ProcessPoolExecutor as its executor.

```
def printing_job():
    print("print this...")

def main():
    executors = {
        'default': ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
    }
    job_defaults = {
        'coalesce': False,
        'max_instances': 3,
        'misfire_grace_time': None
    }
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler(executors=executors,
                                  daemonic=True,
                                  daemon=True)
    scheduler.add_job(printing_job, 'interval', seconds=1)
    scheduler.start()
```

11 processes are spawned, 10 scheduler processes and the main process:

```
user   61428  59435 18 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61456  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61457  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61458  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61459  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61460  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61461  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61462  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61463  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61464  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
user   61465  61428  0 16:25 pts/2    00:00:00 ../bin/python3 ./test.py
```

Only 3 are being used, by the job. I should see at most 4 proceses. The processes should be reaped and re-created.

Is this paradigm not possible with APScheduler?

ProcessPoolExecutor states that max_workers, is the number of workers to be spawned *at most*. The key word being at most, which to me indicates it shouldn't spawn more then it needs.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I am having the same problem. It seems like the ProcessPoolExecutor does not work at all for this reason. It just locks up by trying to create as many processes as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this more or less by customizing a function to generalize the type of parallel and/or concurrent process I'd like to execute. Inside that function you can do the same thing as you are hoping to here. I could not resolve this any other way.